# Post does not work when connected to mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I used the filter function to POST and search the result using hardcoded data.
Then inserted the data in MongoDB and using GET got the entire data.
Then I used POST on MongoDB to search results but I get an error saying filter is undefined.

Controllers file data

```
const restaurantModel = require('../Models/restaurantData');



exports.getRestaurantData =  (req,res) =>{
    var cityname = req.body.city_name;
    var cost = req.body.cost;

    
    var result = restaurantModel.restaurantData.filter(content => content.city_name === cityname && content.cost >= cost); //ES6 syntax used
    console.log(result);
    res.json({ respose : result,
               CityName : cityname,
               cost : cost
    });
};
```

Schema Used :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const restaurantData = new Schema({
    name : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    city_name : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    city : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    area : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    locality :  {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    thumb : {
        type : String,
        required : true        
    },
    cost : {
        type : Number,
        required : true
    },
    address : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    type : {
      type : Array,
      required : true
    },
    Cuisine : {
       type : Array,
       required : true
    }
    
});



module.exports = mongoose.model('restaurantdata', restaurantData , 'restaurantdata');
```

Error received in the console log is below.

```
Connected to MongoDB
Server running at port : 5000
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
    at exports.getRestaurantData (/home/nigel/Documents/Education/API/12.11.2020/Controllers/restaurantData.js:11:49)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/nigel/Documents/Education/API/12.11.2020/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/nigel/Documents/Education/API/12.11.2020/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/nigel/Documents/Education/API/12.11.2020/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/nigel/Documents/Education/API/12.11.2020/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/nigel/Documents/Education/API/12.11.2020/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/nigel/Documents/Education/API/12.11.2020/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/nigel/Documents/Education/API/12.11.2020/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/home/nigel/Documents/Education/API/12.11.2020/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/home/nigel/Documents/Education/API/12.11.2020/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/nigel/Documents/Education/API/12.11.2020/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/nigel/Documents/Education/API/12.11.2020/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/nigel/Documents/Education/API/12.11.2020/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/nigel/Documents/Education/API/12.11.2020/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/nigel/Documents/Education/API/12.11.2020/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /home/nigel/Documents/Education/API/12.11.2020/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mongoose's [`find()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.find) query with the comparison operator [`$gt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/) as:

```
const restaurantModel = require('../Models/restaurantData');

exports.getRestaurantData = async (req,res) => {
    var cityname = req.body.city_name;
    var cost = req.body.cost;

    var result = await restaurantModel.find({
        city_name: cityname,
        const: { $gt: cost }
    }).exec();

    console.log(result);
    res.json({ 
        respose : result,
        CityName : cityname,
        cost : cost
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
exports.getRestaurantData =  (req,res,next) =>{
    restaurantdata.find({
        "city_name": req.body.city_name,
        "cost": req.body.cost
    }, (err, content) => {
        if (err) return next(err);
        else {
            res.json(content);
            // or use "content" however you want.
        }
    });
});
```

to know more: [the documentayion of Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-find)

Comment: I was able to use this solution provided and integrate it with my few commands to get the result. Thank you